# Why we prefer VIF if we can find multicollinearity from correlation matrix as well?

Tags: predictive-modeling, regression

Why we prefer VIF if we can find multicollinearity from the correlation matrix as well? What is the exact logic behind it?

Answer (score 4):

The correlation matrix is not a reliable measurement for multicollinearity  because it only considers the pairwise effects. Unfortunately, multicollinearity is defined as:

> Phenomenon in which **two or more** predictor variables in a multiple regression model are highly correlated,

Do you see the point? You'll need to consider the correlation with all other variables in your data set, not just 1-to-1 pairwise comparison.

VIF addresses the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 10000 rows and 100 columns which have all 100 1s and the rest 0s. Every row has a 1 and the rest 0, a classic one hot encoded matrix. The correlations between two random columns is -0.01010101, which means the correlation matrix has a diagonal of 1s and the rest is -0.01010101. However this matrix is perfectly multicolinear.